# tty_insert_flip_string flipping bits

Tags: linux-kernel, missing-data, tty

I have a custom Linux kernel driver which creates a TTY and sends meta-data with the standard incoming data of a serial line.

The flow is a something like this:

RPMSG->Kernel->Application

The RPMSG contains the data of a serial line and the meta-data.

The message sent by the remote processor is a packed struct and I have verified that on both ends the packing is correct and lines up.

I have the following data which is correct from the Remote Processor and sends it to the kernel which at this point is correct: `0x200A466EE0`. When I use the read function in my application I receive `0x200D466E60`. This means that bits 7 and 27 have been flipped.

My `rpmsg->tty` callback:

```c
static int rpmsg_tty_cb(struct rpmsg_device *rpdev, void *in, int len,
                        void *priv, u32 src) {
    int copied = 0;
    struct rpmsgtty_port *cport = dev_get_drvdata(&rpdev->dev);
    struct tty_struct *tty = dev_get_drvdata(&rpdev->dev);

    /* no one left to give data to, so sleep */
    if (tty == NULL) {
        dev_dbg(&rpdev->dev, "waiting for readers, discard len %d\n",
                len);
        return -ENOTTY;
    }

    /* flush the recv-ed none-zero data to tty node */
    if (len == 0)
        return 0;
    spin_lock_bh(&cport->rx_lock);
    copied = tty_insert_flip_string(&cport->port, in, len);
    if (copied != len)
        dev_err_ratelimited(&rpdev->dev, "RX copy to tty layer failed\n");
    tty_flip_buffer_push(&cport->port);
    spin_unlock_bh(&cport->rx_lock);

    return 0;
}
```

And the application reading:

```c
void *ttyThread(void *args) {
    pthread_t t_id = pthread_self();
    sleep(1);
    struct thread_args *thread_args = (struct thread_args *) args;
    CHECK_MALLOC_THREAD(thread_args);
    thread_args->parser = malloc(sizeof(Parser_t));
    CHECK_MALLOC_THREAD(thread_args->parser);

    thread_args->tty_fd = open(thread_args->tty, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (thread_args->tty_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d opening %s: %s\n", errno, thread_args->tty, strerror(errno));
        free(thread_args);
        return (void *) errno;
    }
    set_interface_attribs(thread_args->tty_fd, thread_args->Baud, thread_args->Parity, thread_args->StopBits,
                          thread_args->DataBits);
    for (;;) {
        M4_Message_t msg;
        int n = read(thread_args->tty_fd, &msg, sizeof(M4_Message_t));
        if (n > 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Thread [%x] %x[%c] number %d\r\n",
                    t_id,
                    msg.Byte,
                    msg.Byte,
                    n);
        }
    }
    free(thread_args->parser);
    free(thread_args);

}
```

Comment: It looks like the 8th bit (7th bit if counting from 0) of each character has been cleared and that CR (0x0D) has been converted to NL (0x0A). So the problem is most likely to be in the termios settings as modified by your `set_interface_attribs` function call.

Comment: @IanAbbott this led me to the right answer